# Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I came across this exception while adding espresso to an android project. I already try the link that comes with this exception

```
**Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ**
```

also I add the following line according to other thread I found

```
**androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'**
```

But the problem still persist. I am using the following configurations:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

Any ideas, thanks.

Comment: Did you try running `./gradlew -q app:dependencies` to see which library is giving you the conflict?

Comment: Go for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36835268/3779239 This link will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 39):

This solve the problem 'Resolved versions for app (24.0.0-beta1) and test app (23.0.1) differ' for me.

```
android{    
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    }
}
```

And do not forget to add following code, if you want to run the AndroidTest

```
 defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.  One has to put `configurations.all` at the bottom of **dependencies** block.

Answer (score 15):

```
dependencies {
    //...

    // Solves "versions for app (23.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'

    // Android JUnit Runner
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    // JUnit4 Rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
}
```

Comment: probably about another library? add all com.android.support... libraries there for androidTestCompile

Comment: Thanks... 

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:XX.XX.XX' your app version

Comment: Gradle is building fine but it shows error for 
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
For Different version of support library versions

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays when you create a new project on Android Studio, it adds this dependency by default:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

The `exclude` section is probably to avoid the conflict mentioned in the question. I also faced this issue when trying to add `runner:0.5` and `rules:0.5` dependencies. My solution was to apply the same piece of code above on them:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

It works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

annotation library is used by all three dependancies rules:0.5', runner:05 and espresso-core:2.2.2, so following worked for me

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild project solved the issue.

In Android studio in the toolbar.. Build>Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 0):

```
сompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test:runner:0.5"){
   exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'){
   exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

It's a solution

Comment: Why would this solve the problem?  I don't get it.  I tried it, and it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: My dependencies versions:
<!-- language: gradle -->
        androidGradleToolsVersion = '2.1.0'
        androidBuildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'
        androidSDKVersion = 23
        androidSupportLibVersion = '23.3.0'
<!-- language: lang-none -->

try to change its. Or try to use latest versions. But I think you'll need to use piece of code above nonetheless.