# Android support library error after updating to 23.3.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have been using android support v4 23.1.1 and recently tried to update it to 23.3.0 ( the latest one when this was asked) but I got the following error:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'.
>   Resolved versions for app (23.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ.
>   See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

So far I have found this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206137

I went to both the links but I could not fix my issue, how do I fix this issue?

**Edit:**

I have these in my dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

Previously all the versions were `23.1.1` and it worked fine the error occurred after updating

Edit:

```
Gradle Version 2.10
Gradle Plugin Version 2.0.0
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

For those people who are still facing this problem just add this line to your dependencies.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
```

It solved my problem.

**UPDATE:**

If you have this error nowadays, you can just insert the new versioncode (`23.3.0` in this case, or `27.1.1` in May '18) as it is described in the error into the above described solution.

Comment: Tried your solution but still facing error:

`Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'. Resolved versions for app (23.4.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.`

Gradle dependency:     `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'`

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Try adding  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

Comment: Still leaves me with `Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'. Resolved versions for app (23.4.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.`. But upon adding `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` results in errors within values.xml `Error:(72) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'. ...`

Comment: SO - Stack Overflow

Comment: Had to do the same to get my project to build since I upgraded to Android Studio 2.3. Thanks

Answer (score 50):

For those who still facing the problem, above answer did not help me in android studio 2.2 Preview.

add this to your gradle file.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
 }
}
```

This fixed my issue.

Reference:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/05a57bf43b9b61f16d32cbe8717af77cd608b0fb/build.gradle#L136-L140

Comment: Seems to have fixed mine too, in AS 2.2 Preview 3 that is

Answer (score 20):

Just exemplifying Akshayraj's answer

Original Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    [...]

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

}
```

Received error:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'.
>   Resolved versions for app (25.1.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ.
>   See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details. "

**FIXED** when I added:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'
```

Final File:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    [...]

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

Answer (score 10):

My orignal app.gradle had:

```
dependencies {
    // App dependencies
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' 

    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
}
```

which resulted in following error:
***Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.4.0) and test app (22.2.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details*.**

After reading the link suggested in error, I found theses lines:

> When instrumentation tests are run, both the main APK and test APK
>   share the same classpath. Gradle build will fail if the main APK and
>   the test APK use the same library (e.g. Guava) but in different
>   versions. If gradle didn't catch that, your app could behave
>   differently during tests and during normal run (including crashing in
>   one of the cases).

So I modified my app.gradle dependencies to:

```
dependencies {
    // App dependencies
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
}
```

Even after the above change gradle was not happy :-(:
*Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.4.0) and test app **(23.3.0)** differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.*

Change in test apk version was different! So I modified the version string as pasted below which worked for me:

(Nirvana)

```
dependencies {
    // App dependencies
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' // main APK

    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0' //test APK
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
}
```

Comment: a decent example on android gradle usage --> https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately, but I see how your answer works. +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while to get out of this error. But this is what has worked for me, give it a try:

**NOTE:** Am using compileSdkVersion 26

I removed both androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
& androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' in the dependencies block in build.gradle(Module: app). So I ended up with this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.date.brian.cradletest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I hope this comes in handy!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the same version for app and androidTest APKs. To do this, specify the same version as your app,

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'
```

where 24.1.1 is the version number of the dependency used in your app

Answer (score 2):

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, **The build tool version has to align with the dependency versions**. So lets say the build tool version is `26.1.0`, the Gradle dependency version has to obey it.

The simplest way is to create a version variable & use it. See the example below

```
ext {
    buildVersion = '26.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${buildVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude 'annotations'. No harm will be done

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **Android Studio**
2. Navigate to *Project > Gradle Scripts > build.gradle (Module:app)*
3. Add `dependencies {androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:xx.x.x'}`
4. You can replace *xx.x.x* to version which is showing in an error
5. Save Gradle script
6. Build Project

Hope this will work! :)

Answer (score 0):

It was solved after adding the last line:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove test dependency from build.gradel file for resolving the issues

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
Resolves dependency versions across test and production APKs, specifically, transitive
dependencies. This is required since Espresso internally has a dependency on support-annotations.
*/
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.