# Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project

Tags: android, android-support-library

After a short time I return to use Android Studio.
When I create a new project I encounter this problem

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

I found many solutions to this problem but none of them worked.
[Android support library error after updating to 23.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833606/android-support-library-error-after-updating-to-23-3-0)

I have these in my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same version of support library for appCompat and support-annotations. So, change the dependencies from:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

Then, try to **excluding** existing support-annotations from espresso with:

```
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Comment: This syntax of excluding doesnt work in for me. I've found an other one, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I'v got the same version conflict of *support-annotations* module.
The difference was that i've tried to decrease version which is used by test libs.

```
dependencies {
def withoutSupportAnnotations = {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'}
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2', withoutSupportAnnotations
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', withoutSupportAnnotations}
```

This reusable variable helped me.
Also *test:runner* and *espresso* use the same version of annotations (*27.2.1* in my case)